# Spring Boot 1.5.3 local CDF server

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to extend local CDF server.

I am using the following dependencies:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dataflow-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-dataflow.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-task-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-task.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server-local</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I can't figure out what are the latest compatible versions of:

- spring-cloud-dataflow.version
- spring-cloud-task.version
- spring-cloud

Where can I see what versions are compatible with `Spring Boot 1.5.3.RELEASE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We aren't compatible with 1.5.3 yet. The recent 1.2 RC1 release is at 1.5.2 - see [release notes](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/releases/tag/v1.2.0.RC1).

The 1.2 GA is planned to be on the same release as well.

Comment: Thanks! But apps are compatible with 1.5.3 right? `app-starters-core-dependencies:1.2.0.RELEASE` is compatible with 1.5.3?

Comment: No. The latest Bacon-release-train for [stream apps](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/core/blob/19f72de5c2f4937a0c67bddb7d6ff09277d97af6/pom.xml#L25) are at 1.5.2 as well. Given the property whitelisting concepts that we support in SCDF, we tend to make sure the "core" compatibility is good before we upgrade the apps. One other thing - we pull Spring Boot through `spring-cloud-build-1.3.1`/`spring-cloud Dalston.RELEASE`, which brings 1.5.2. Until the spring-cloud BOM is updated, we cannot get to it.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure where to look up the current versions, appreciate the links.